# Switching input audio source in webrtc, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, avaudiosession

I' m making on a call product with WebRTC. and

How can switch input audio source like built in mic - airpods or etcs?

I initialize :

```swift
  self.rtcAudioSession.lockForConfiguration()

  do {
    try self.rtcAudioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord.rawValue)
    try self.rtcAudioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat.rawValue)
    try self.rtcAudioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
    try self.rtcAudioSession.setActive(true)
  } catch { }

    self.rtcAudioSession.unlockForConfiguration()
  }
```

and I tried below code blocks when the `AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification` reached:

```swift
  // on bluetooth
  let inputs = audioSession.availableInputs

  for input in inputs! {
     if input.portType.rawValue == AVAudioSession.Port.bluetoothHFP.rawValue {
      do {
         try self.rtcAudioSession.setPreferredInput(input)
      } catch let error {
        print("Setting BLE Port: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
  }

  // on native 
    ...
```

- expected : replace the input audio source
- happend : the `setPreferredInput` line runned, but anything happend. (with no error, no replace audio input.)

environment detail :

- WebRTC M105: https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/ios
- Xcode 14, iOS 16

is there an another proper way?
any ideas will be appreciated. thanks :

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?" What exactly is your hardware configuration? Does the `setPreferredInput` line run? Does it return an error? What is the audio session's category and mode? Have you activated the session (as required in the documentation)? What exactly happens and what exactly do you expect to happen here?

Comment: Oh thanks, I will explain it in more detail.

Comment: I documented in more detail, but please let me know if there is any missing info @RobNapier

Comment: You're trying to set the preferred input inside of a `routeChangeNotification` callback? That would at best create an infinite loop (changing the input will change the route, posting another `routeChangeNotification`). Alternately, changes in the middle of the notification may be ignored (since they would create an infinite loop). Or what do you mean by "below code blocks when the AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification reached." What is your hardware configuration? Do you have exactly one input that supports HFP? (Your code will try to set *all* HFP devices in turn.)

Comment: And what type is `rtcAudioSession`? `lockForConfiguration` is an AVCaptureDevice method, but `setCategory` is an AVAudioSession method. Is this specific to a third-party library you're using? The link you've given is for Chrome, not Swift.

Comment: Your code is also throwing away all errors with `catch{}`. It's quite possible that the system is telling you what you're doing wrong, and you're ignoring it.

Comment: Your initial configuration code is for `rtcAudioSession`, but your `setPreferredInput` method is on `audioSession`. Are these the same object?

Comment: Thanks and sorry to late, I am using [googleWebRTC](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/ios/) library and corrected right now.

`What is your hardware configuration? Do you have exactly one input that supports HFP?` ->    I didn't understand it exactly, is there a method to configure hardware settings?

Comment: -> and `lockForConfiguration` is webrtc-iOS method ([#RTCAudioSession](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/c5aea65b769993a60d67952e2ea9da372a93782c/webrtc/modules/audio_device/ios/objc/RTCAudioSession.mm#186))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248353/discussion-between-lidium-and-rob-napier).